# Finding out my user agent and putting it on my website

Tags: html, agent

Like you can go on http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ website and see what user agent you are coming from. I need the similar feature on my website. I tried to view source and didn't find nothing. I am basically looking forward for the html code to find the user agent of people that come on my website, I am just debugging at this point. I am looking to put the coding on my home page so that I can confirm what device the user is coming from. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

HTML is not a programming language. It has no means to get this information.

The proper approach is to read the [User-Agent HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) using a server side language (and optional web framework) of your preference (e.g. in [Perl/Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Runtime-5.80032/lib/Catalyst/Request.pm)), and then output it to the page (after sanitizing it to make it HTML safe).

Similar data is also available to client side JavaScript via the `navigator` object.

Answer (score 2):

The user agent can be whatever the user wants it to be - so don't rely on this for security.

From the client side, you could use some JavaScript in your HTML:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.write(navigator.userAgent);
</script>
```

I don't recommend using `document.write` though.

For the mentioned web site, they're likely checking server side with the HTTP header. To grab this in PHP, you can use:

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

But as Quentin said, sanitise this as it could output anything the user likes.

Comment: All the links above mentioned what needs to be done. But you gave me the exact coding, Great saved my time . Thanks Oblig =)